# get rid of blank rows at the end in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a very strange issue with a `DataGridView`, whenever I try to put some data through queries I get one extra blank row at the end. 
How do I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
```

There is a row at the bottom for the user to manually add data. I think you might want to remove this

Answer (score 0):

before fill the data in the Grid view 
Write down the `Gridview1.Rows.Clear`
Then Fill the data.